# Upload file to Parse Server on Flutter web

Tags: flutter, web, parse-server, flutter-web

Is there any way to upload files to Parse Server using Flutter web.?

One better, How to select file from system and upload it to Parse Server on Flutter web?

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.0.27 (not yet on pub.dev) file support for web was added.